# Can I send special operators in autohotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

I want an AHK script which when I press <kbd>NumPad7</kbd> returns `{`.

Now, in my keyboard `{` is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>´</kbd>

But the script

```
`NumPad7::
    Send, ^!´
 return`
```

does nothing for some reason.

---

Update: It does work with regular keys like this:

```
p::
Send; ^!´
return
```

---

Edit 2: 
<kbd>NumLock</kbd> had to be on, now it works fine.

Comment: Here's the entire script: `Numpad7::{`

Comment: Nope, still not working...

Comment: Works for me, or I don't understand what you really want to achieve.

Comment: "Not working" is an extremely lazy problem description and is a useless statement. Explain _exactly_ what is not working and why it confuses you.

Comment: With not working I meant "When I input the aforementioned key it does not output anything"

But it is solved, Just had to turn BlockNum on

Answer (score 0):

This script gives you `{` from <kbd>7</kbd> on numeric keypad regardless of <kbd>NumLock</kbd> state:

```
NumPad7::
NumPadHome::
 SendRaw {
 Return
```